# KornShell or Bash Shell for ETL process?

Tags: bash, scripting, ksh, data-warehouse, etl

I am working on a project where I need to load the data into data warehouse using ETL process. I have data in csv, unstructured and flat file format. I am thinking about using shell scripting to carry out the ETL process. I know little about both bash shell and KornShell (ksh) but I am very new in ETL process. So my question is what is the better option for ETL process. Whether I should use Bash Shell or KornShell?

The answer from user experienced with ETL process and shell scripting is highly appreciated.

Thank in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't be using either shell for ETL, I'd be using Perl, which has _much_ more power for data transformation work. If you _must_ use a shell, you'll probably find bash is both more powerful and has more helpers on the net.

Comment: There is nothing magical about ETL scripts or programs, they're like any other application: there are some common practices and tools available that you can either use or get ideas from, but in the end you have to write code yourself to implement your requirements. So I can only suggest that you do some research and make a decision based on the experience, skills and existing coding standards in your organization. 10 different people will give you 10 different answers on how to implement an ETL solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, my ETL processes use SQL statements to do in-database transformation, so they're really "ELT" process. The shell simply serves as the tool to move files around, execute data loads & extracts, and execute SQL statements. If your DW is on a sufficiently powerful system, it's usually the best place to do the transformation work, unless you are set on having a system living outside of the EDW that does data transformations.

The choice of shell for such an ELT process that I've described is really one of maintenance. Who will be supporting this when you're gone? Does the company have lots of folks who know bash, but only one that knows KSH? Or is it 99% a .NET shop? Then I'd suggest writing your ETL in little C# console apps. The choice of the language you use to execute your ETL, when you're not using a real "ETL" tool, should be focused on these factors, not on the 'best' language.

Answer (score 3):

Korn is slightly more portable.  Bash is a lot more powerful.  "Bourne shell" is a good least common denominator.

All things being equal, I'd recommend "bash".  Especially if your platform is Linux.

IMHO ..

PS:

The name "bash" stands for "Bourne Again Shell", a pun on its heritage from the original "Bourne" shell.  Bourne scripts are bash-compatible, but not vice versa.

Comment: I *gave* you an answer in the context of ETL process.  You can manipulate your .csv with whatever tools you feel comfortable with.  You can use Bourne, Korn or Bash.  Or go out and buy a commercial tool.  Or write something in VB.Net or Perl.  Totally up to you!  Look here for more info: [etltools.com vendor survey](https://www.etltool.com/order.php) - it's only € 725 :).